# FetchRequest within Method called from performBlock NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Within a `performBlock` I handoff its `managedObjectContext` to other methods which use it for core data access. The `managedObjectContext` is a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and has the `NSMainQueueconCurrencyType` as a parent. As soon as one of the called methods within the `performBlock` execute a fetch request, the applications dies without any error. The OS X Console outputs the following:

```
BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
```

Has anyone an idea what is causing this?

I'm using XCode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.

### Update

I discovered that this problem only occurs within a `SenTestingKit` case as a static library. If I include the library into a regular iOS App it's gone. Any Ideas?

Comment: Your problem is likely in how you set up the core data stack in your unit test. Can you post the code on how you are setting up the ManagedObjectContext in your unit test?

Comment: I use the default setup of the CoreDataStack, generated by Xcode, and changed it by only one line: `_managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];`

Comment: I too ran into this when using XCTest in the latest Xcode 8.1b3 (well 8.1GM just came out recently but still). I found that if you have a main MOC created on the main queue and a private background MOC created on a background queue on-the-fly, if you make the main MOC the parent of the background MOC and then attempt to fetch from the child, with or without -performBlock it will lock up Xcode if using dispatch_group_wait while waiting for the async test or will crash the test if using waitForExpectationsWithTimeout ("stalled on the main thread" error).

Comment: If you create two MOCs pointing to the same persistent store coordinator, one being a main queue type and the other a private queue type, you can fetch from the private queue MOC from a background queue using performBlock without any issues. However, you'll still be mixing the newer queue concurrency model with the older thread containment model for merging between main and background MOCs, which some see as taboo (not this guy though! http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/4/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your objects designed to be running on background threads into `NSBlockOperation` in a `NSOperationQueue` will alleviate queue blocking errors between your child and parent contexts.

You should also remove the `performBlock` calls of your child context. Child automatically does requests to the parent queue on its private queue which automatically calls the parent context using the parent contexts `performBlock`. Your existing calls will work *if your code happens to not be running on the main thread*, but will cause a deadlock if it runs on the main thread (child and parent are locking main thread) which is what happens in a unit test. The only place I've seen this documented by Apple was in this 2012 WWDC video.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=214

Comment: Using Core Data works with any problems until I create a child context. So the setup of my Core Data stack for testing works.

Comment: Your queues are blocking each other.

Comment: How is that possible if I call performBlock on the child context and only interact with the child within the block?

Comment: Adding explanation of your deadlocks to answer